# Angular 2: How to set double, float, int & boolean type params in GET & POST requests

Tags: javascript, http, angular

In Angular 2 we are using **URLSearchParams** to set URL parameters in **GET** & **POST** requests.

```
var params = new URLSearchParams();
params.set('param1', param1);
```

I am using following way to use **double** and **int** type params.

```
longitude: number;
size: number;
params.set('longitude', longitude.toString());
params.set('size', size.toString());
```

But we can use only String type parameters here. What would be the best way to use **double**, **float** and **boolean** type parameters ?

Comment: What do you mean, exactly? `URLSearchParams` only take string parameters because URL parameters are always strings. Any other type you'd have to convert to string, like you are doing. There's really not much else to say...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As the names implies, URLSearchParams are part of the URL. URLs are need to be represented as string. If you need to distinguish between string, double float and boolean, then you can invent your own encoding and parse it accordingly on the receiver site.

An example:

```
var floatStr = encodeURIComponent(JSON.stringify({type: 'float', value: longitude.toString()}));
// params.set('param1', floatStr);

....

var json = JSON.parse(decodeURIComponent(param1));
if(json.type === 'float') {
  var longitude = parseFloat(json.value);
}
```